# Material-ui List select multiple items

Tags: material-ui

As shown in the documentation example you can implement a [selectable List](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list).

I was wondering how would one be able to make the list to support multiple selections.

The method that was used in the example is `makeSelectable`. There doesn't seem to be any documentation regarding that method and I wasn't able to find anything substantial in the issues of their git project.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a state variable `selectedItems` to keep track of selected items of the list.
ListItem supports `checkboxes`, so you can create a checkbox for each ListItem, add an `onCheck` handler to it and pass to it a unique value to identify which checkbox is checked and based on that you can modify the state variable `selectedItems`.

Alternatively, you can use **Menu** in place of **List** as it has the property `multiple`. You can set it to true and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Aanchal.

Comment: Happy to help :)